# Find all objects in JSON by key and merge it to new array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an JSON with some contacts. I retrieve it with a service and the following function.

I would like to create an new array 'contactList' whith all combined firstnames and lastnames and a added '@'-char. Thank you for your hints.

```
this.dataService.getContacts()
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.contactPersons = data;
    console.log('data' + JSON.stringify(this.contactPersons));
});
```

**Example contact.json**

```
[
  {
    "firstname": "Antonie",
    "lastname": "Klain",
 ...
```

**Expected Output**

```
contactList = [
    '@Antonie Klain',
    '@... ...',
    '@... ...',
    '@... ...',
    '@... ...',
    ...
  ]
```

Comment: What is that you have done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map` to achieve this.

```js
const names = [{
    "firstname": "Antonie",
    "lastname": "Klain",
  },
  {
    "firstname": "Antonie2",
    "lastname": "Klain2",
  }
];

const fnames = names.map(({
  firstname,
  lastname
}) => '@' + firstname + ' ' + lastname);

console.log(fnames);
```